# Is there any easier way to declare a collection as it do in Javascript

Tags: java

Is there any way can I use Java to declare a collection as it does in Javascript

I want something like this to simplify declare:

```
List<String> list = ["item"];
String item = list[0];

Set<String> set = {"item"};

Map<String, Integer> map = {"key" : 1};
int value = map["key"];
```

Comment: Java is chocked full of collections. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: No, just do it the java way. If you want nice syntax, there's Kotlin

Comment: Q: Is there any way can I use Java to declare a collection?  A: Sure.  You just need to 1) Choose the best collection for your purposes, and 2) Use the correct Java syntax.  Look here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html  Q: Can I declare collection as it do in Javascript?  A: NO!  Java <> Javascript!!!!!

Comment: I know the  type of collection in Java and its normal declared method, what I want is find out a possible way to simplify its declared process

Comment: There's no way. If it was so easy people would not have to invent a whole new language just for that... (well, you can make your own code preprocessor instead of learning Kotlin from scratch, but you'll probably end up reinventing the wheel)

Comment: Well, next time it would be better (avoid other people being frustrated) to show what you know already (the old/new way to create a collection), and that you want some nicer way -- but the question still doesn't make much sense because it would be weird if there's a way but not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you are using Java 9.

Your examples above would be:

```
List<String> list = List.of("item"); // List.of("a","b","c" ...)
String item = list[0]; // wont work
String item = list.get(0); // works

Set<String> set = Set.of("item"); // Set.of("a","b","c" ...)

Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("key", 1); // Map.of("key", 1, "keyB", 2, "keyC", 3 ...)
int value = map["key"]; // wont work
int value = map.get("key"); // works
```

Comment: This is shorter and definitely nicer than the old `new Data(); value.add(something);`, but strictly speaking, not what OP is asking for. although it's also possible that this would be useful to OP if they didn't know about it before.

Comment: I interpreted what the OP wanted as "I want to declare _and initialise_ a collection in one statement, like its possible to do in JS". I dont see what else could be being asked for here?

Comment: @user202729 What the OP wants isn’t possible.  This answer is the closest solution that compiles.

Comment: Thanks, @Kirit, I know this solution but that is not the way I want, from the answers above  I know it is not possible to do the declare as in Javascript